# assets/vendor.css problems in Ember 2 after installing Picnic

Tags: ember-cli

working on the ember-cli-101 tutorial, and searches have shown that others have posted on this issue, but it all dates back to a year ago and Ember 1.x. I'm using 2.4.3, though. here is how it goes.

`bower install picnic --save`

ember-cli-build.js:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
  });


  app.import('bower_components/picnic/releases/plugins.min.css');
  app.import('bower_components/picnic/releases/picnic.min.css');

  return app.toTree();
};
```

app/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Borrowers</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    {{content-for "head"}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/borrowers.css">

    {{content-for "head-footer"}}
  </head>
  <body>
    {{content-for "body"}}

    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/borrowers.js"></script>

    {{content-for "body-footer"}}
  </body>
</html>
```

starting the server....

```
$ ember server --proxy http://api.ember-cli-101.com
version: 2.4.2
Proxying to http://api.ember-cli-101.com
Livereload server on http://localhost:49152
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
The Broccoli Plugin: [SimpleConcat: Concat: Vendor Styles/assets/vendor.css] failed with:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

and the fix is... in ember-cli-build.js, you should only have this line for Picnic

```
app.import('bower_components/picnic/picnic.min.css');
```

there is no `plugins.min.css` file anymore and `picnic.min.css` is in Picnic's root directory, not `picnic/releases`.